# Encoding a video (mp4) in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I want to store a video file in sqlite database and retrieve it from the database.
I can store it in database with code that I have.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/download/video.mp4");
byte[] image = new byte [fileInputStream.available()];
fileInputStream.read(image);

ContentValues valuse = new ContentValues();
valuse.put("a",image);
db.insert("tb",null,valuse);
fileInputStream.close();
```

And I want to retrieve it from database and play it.

Comment: What not working?

Answer (score 0):

Storing a movie in a `SQLite` database (or any other database actually) is a bad idea from my experience.

What you can do instead is save the video file on your device and save the path to this file in the database.

Another solution is to store your videos online and load them from your online cloud this way:

```
String LINK = "http://www.yourcloud.com/yourideo.mp4";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

But for sure **DONT** store videos in the database.

Comment: thanks. but I must store it in the database .  if you have any ideas about how to do it please let me know.

Comment: You cant do that. you already have the path, just save the path in the database.

Comment: it's just an example.I don't want to let client access files out of the application.

Comment: So encrypt the files. that's another situation, not related to your question topic.